# Best way to send data from Microsoft bot to Microsoft Dynamics NAV

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I need to create a bot with Azure bot service that will need to send the data it gets directly from the user to Microsoft Dynamics NAV. Is there a direct way to do this (since both services are Microsoft), and if not, what do you recommend as a way to send the data to NAV? (Data might include new columns for tables or commands to create, update, or delete tables, probably other requirements that I don't know yet, I'm new to NAV)

Comment: spelling; grammar; noise reduction.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. The generic answer would be: "is there an API for Dynamics NAV? Looks like there is one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/enabling-apis-for-dynamics-nav"